# How are stat gains determined on level up in Mario & Luigi: Paper Jam?

Tags: mario-and-luigi-paper-jam

When Mario, Luigi, or Paper Mario level up in Mario & Luigi: Paper Jam, their stats are raised. So far, I've seen each of the individual stats raised by an amount between 1-3 during the level up animation.

I understand this is different from the previous games, per the [Mario Wiki](http://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_%26_Luigi:_Paper_Jam), which states that
`Bonus points can no longer be applied to stats upon leveling up.` What determines how much a stat is raised, then? Is it...

- Static, set gain. For example, it's coded and predetermined that Luigi will get +2 to HP at level 3?
- Dynamic, variable gain. Based on some criteria (enemies defeated, type of enemy defeated, time since last level up, etc.?), the game calculates that Luigi earned a +2 in HP at level 3?

If the gain is dynamic, what calculates the stat gain?

Comment: Very sure that every level has a static value that they will gain. Additionally once you hit a new level tier you can choose a bonus "perk" and with this you can choose a stat to increase more at each additional level gained. I just beat this last night actually....

Comment: @Dupree3 I'm at level 5 now, so about to rank up... good to know about the perk gain. Do you know if the static stat gain is documented, or even better, a list of the stat gains to expect by character/level? If so, that can definitely be expanded into an answer. :)

Comment: I cannot find anything to credit my first comment or I would, it is just something I would have to assume. Additionally at some point you can do individual stat increases through beans, this is through the start menu.